# Listar archivos visibles

Tags: java

Cuando en un programa hago esto:

```
File[] ficheros2=new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() { 
public boolean accept(File fichero2) {
return fichero2.isFile();
}
});            
for(File fichero :ficheros2) {
  System.out.print( ficheros2.length+ "                  ");
  System.out.print(fichero.getName()+"            ");
  System.out.println(fichero.getAbsoluteFile())   ;   
}                      }
     catch(Exception e) {
     }
```

Me saca un listado de todos los archivos ( SOLO FICHEROS NO DIRECTORIOS) Hasta aquí correcto.. Pero como puedo hacer para que no me muestre los ocultos?

Necesito que el programa me muestre los archivos visibles. Los ocultos que los evite.

Para ocultos sé que existe isHidden pero y para los visibles?  Quizás se tiene que hacer con isHidden pero no veo la forma..

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez podrías negar la condición:

```
File[] ficheros2=new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() { 
    public boolean accept(File fichero2) {
        return fichero2.isFile() && !fichero2.isHdden();
    }
});
```

Comment: GRACIAS!! Me va perfecto! :)